# 한국대학교 전화번호 부탁드립니다.

Tags: grammar, meaning, spoken-korean, phrase-meaning

한국대학교 전화번호 부탁드립니다.

I am not sure about the meaning of this sentence. 
부탁 = a request  
드리다 is the honorific form of 주다.

So, does this mean "please give me the phone number of Korea University"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that means 'Please give(tell) me the phone number of Hangook(Korea) University.'

If you are able to read a bit complicated Korean, it would be helpful to see this Q&A: http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=4663

Short summary of the above document will be this: '드리다' can stand for 1) "giving something to elders" when its usage is verb, and 2) "doing something to elders" when its usage is suffix(right after verbal noun). So '드리다' in the above sentence you posted would be the second one - suffix.